# What does $$ in javac generated name mean?

Tags: java, jar, lambda, javac, anonymous-inner-class

When shifting through java call graph generated by libraries like DependencyFinder and java-callgraph, I found out that java compiler generate names for anonymous functions, inner classes, etc.

I've found out the meaning of a couple of them (please correct if I'm wrong):

- `org.example.Bar$Foo` refers to `Foo`, which is an inner class of `org.example.Bar`.
- `org.example.Bar$1` refers to an anonymous class declared inside one of the methods of `org.example.Bar`.
- `org.example.Bar.lambda$spam$1()` refers to a lambda declared inside of `org.example.Bar.spam()` method.

However, I also found:

1. `org.example.Bar$$Lambda$2.args$1`
2. `org.example.Bar$$Lambda$2.call()`
3. `org.example.Bar$$Lambda$7.lambdaFactory$()`
4. `org.example.Bar$$Lambda$7.get$Lambda()`

What does the four name above refer to? What does double dollar (`$$`) mean?

Comment: It's just a separator, it could be anything.

Comment: It seems obvious that the double $$ is simply used for the special "new classes" used for lambda expressions. So $ is used to separate names for inner classes, and $$ marks lambda-expression-based inner classes.

Comment: Update: I found a reference in the specification: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/jls8.pdf - reading it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The classes for lambda expressions are not `javac` generated, but created at runtime by the JRE. Their names are completely unspecified and you can’t rely on any naming scheme.

But obviously, Oracle’s current JRE has a recognizable pattern. It appends `$$Lambda$n` to the name of the defining class whereas `n` is an increasing number, which reflects the *creation* order at runtime, rather than any property of the compiled code.

You can verify this with the following program:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        if(args.length==0) {
            final boolean meFirst = Math.random()<0.5;
            if(meFirst) {
                Runnable r=Test::main;
                System.out.println("first run:\t"+r.getClass());
            }
            main("second run");
            if(!meFirst) {
                Runnable r=Test::main;
                System.out.println("first run:\t"+r.getClass());
            }
        }
        else {
            Runnable r=Test::main;
            System.out.println(args[0]+":\t"+r.getClass());
            if(args[0].equals("second run")) main("last run");
        }
    }
}
```

Depending on the state of the random `meFirst` flag, it will print either

```
first run:  class Test$$Lambda$1
second run: class Test$$Lambda$2
last run:   class Test$$Lambda$2
```

or

```
second run: class Test$$Lambda$1
last run:   class Test$$Lambda$1
first run:  class Test$$Lambda$2
```

It shows that the first generated class always gets the number `1`, regardless of whether it’s one of the first two method references instantiated in the first `main` invocation or the third method reference, instantiated in the first recursion. Further, the 3rd execution always encounters the same class as the 2nd, as it’s the same method reference expression (note: distinct *expression*, as the target of all expressions is the same) and the class is re-used.

Depending on the version, you may further see something like `/number` appended to the names, which hints that the names really don’t matter, as each of these classes has another unique identifier (they are so called “anonymous classes” which you can’t locate via `ClassLoader` and name).

Field names like `args$n` within these classes represent the n’th captured value. Since the [`LambdaMetafactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory.html) has no knowledge about the actual names of the captured variables, it has no other choice but to generate such names.

---

But as said, that’s an implementation artifact. It’s possible to maintain such a naming pattern, as long as a new class is generated for each creation site in each defining class. But since the specification allows arbitrary sharing/reusing of classes and instances representing equivalent lambda expressions (doing the same) and method references (targeting the same method), such a naming pattern is not possible with every implementation strategy.